# Old JavaScript no longer working. Chrome says Event.path is deprecated, but I don't use Event.path in my code

Tags: javascript, event-handling, deprecation-warning

I built a [game of concentration](https://tay.codes/concentration/) over a year ago. I tried to run it today and when you click on the back of a "card" it's supposed to reveal a picture, but it does not. Chrome dev tools says "Event.path is deprecated and will be removed. Please use Event.composedPath() instead."

Nowhere in my code do I use Event.path and I can't seem to figure out what specifically is broken.

Here is the code I do have for a click event. The first function is repeated for all 24 cards and calls the second function which is supposed to reveal the picture "underneath" the back of the card and if both revealed pictures are the same they remain revealed, otherwise they both get reset to show the back of the card.

```js
//onClick functions for all card images
  pic1.onclick = () => {
    console.log(revealedPics); //this sends the file link of the revealed picture to the console
    if (isClicked(pic1) === false) {
        pic1.src = picArray[0];
        checkIfMatch(pic1);
      } else if (trackRevealedCardsArray.includes(pic1.src) === true) {
        return;
      } else {
        pic1.src = backOfCard;
      }
      console.log(revealedPics);
}

//Check if two revealed images are a match
const checkIfMatch = (pic) => {
    if (revealedPics === 1) {
        firstPic = pic;
    } else if (revealedPics === 2) {
        secondPic = pic;
        if (firstPic.src === secondPic.src) {
            revealedPics = 0;
            totalPairs--;
            trackRevealedCardsArray.push(firstPic.src);
            console.log(`total pairs ${totalPairs}`);
            if (totalPairs === 0) {
                window.setTimeout(gameOver, 500);
            }
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                firstPic.src = backOfCard;
                secondPic.src = backOfCard;
            }, 800);
            window.setTimeout(resetRevealedPics, 800);
        }
    } 
}
```

I've checked to make sure all my paths are correct and they are. When I run the same html files from my local drive it works perfectly.

Comment: I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: pic1 is not defined`. Please fix it.

Comment: When/where do you get that error? The code pasted in my post is not meant to be run by itself.

Comment: Please provde a [mcve] (as text in your question, not behind a link) that can be copied and pasted to debug it.